# SSD getting warm when using fedora

Tags: linux, fedora

This is a strange issue I'm having. I've just installed fedora 36 on my laptop, I previously was using ubuntu 22.04 which did not have this problem. This wouldn't be such a big problem for me if my SSD was not right underneath the wrist rest, acting like a small heater and making working on my laptop very annoying.

I couldn't find anything relating to this issue on the fedora forums and don't know what to exactly give you guys to help diagnose the problem.

Comment: Next to impossible to say. At a guess fedora could be accessing the disk more than Ubuntu did. To find out what's going on in terms of disk access you could have a look w/ `iotop` or similar tools, and if you find that there's lot of activity while you're not doing much you can try to isolate the most active processes and check whether they can be stopped or disabled.

Comment: SSDs have power management - perhaps Ubuntu enables it and Fedora doesn't. It's most likely down to the kernels they are using.

Comment: Update: Ssd heats up only when I charge the laptop and also, iotop is showing normal SSD usage, nothing is causing huge reads and writes.

Comment: I think artem is on the right path here, power management seems to be the issue here.

Comment: Any ideas on how I can give you guys power stats regarding my SSD?